# How to call dispatch events specific for Mobile?

Tags: event-observer, magento2.3, rest-api

- How to call dispatch event for REST API's only in
  mobile devices.

Comment: define your event in events.xml in etc/webapi_rest in your custom module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by defining `events.xml` in `webapi_rest` folder.

**Example**

> vendor/magento/module-quote/etc/webapi_rest/events.xml

Magento is doing the same in **quote module** for sending mail for specific area `REST`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_success">
        <observer name="sendEmail" instance="Magento\Quote\Observer\Webapi\SubmitObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```